# Possible to use Wifi Direct with iOS? Or interact with Airdrop with Android?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, wifi-direct

I need to send data between iOS and Android where there is no internet connection.

This leaves me with NFC, but I hear the iOS limits usage of NFC to apple pay.

I looked at using Bluetooth LE, but not sure how to go about this.

The best option is WifiDirect, which I already do in Android and would like to use in iOS.

Does iOS support WifiDirect?  Or a variation of this, where I create an enterprise "profile" and push that wifi profile onto the device at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

No Directly you wont be able to communicate from android to iOS.
But by using  a simple TCP Socket connection you can create a communication bridge between two.

On **Android**, use the `Socket` class, on **iOS** use socket programming.

Here are some useful tutorials for that.

[Raywenerlich Tutorial with sample code](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/networking-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server)

[Manicdev Tutorial with sample code and explanations](https://maniacdev.com/2011/06/tutorial-building-a-simple-ios-tcp-socket-based-app-client-and-server)

If you do not want to do it with IPs then search for [zeroconfig/bonjour](https://learn.adafruit.com/bonjour-zeroconf-networking-for-windows-and-linux/overview)

Comment: using sockets implies that I already have a "network" established.

Comment: @LamonteCristo Yes, using sockets implies you have an established network which is the MAIN problem when communicating between Android and iOS.